# Serialize to xml using a class with multiple classes

Tags: c#, xml

I am using an asp.net and C# to serialize some entered data using a class. This class was generated from an xsd file. I am using this class to generate an xml file. I am struggling to understand how I can reference all these classes and serialize it to one xml file.

Here is my class code. It is in a separate file within my project:

```
 namespace Ce
{
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.33440.
// 



public partial class AddRequest
{

    private CDocument cDocumentField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "x")]
    public CDocument CDocument
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cDocumentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cDocumentField = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class CDocument
{

    private CaseA caseAField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "x")]
    public CaseA CaseA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.caseAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.caseAField = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class CaseA
{

    public string dCTextField;

    private string dLField;



    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "x")]
    public string DCText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dCTextField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dCTextField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "x")]
    public string DLU
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dLField = value;
        }
    }

}
}
```

To serialize I have this in my code-behind in a button click event:

```
 protected void CaseSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

CaseA CSerialize = new CaseA();
    CSerialize.DCText = casetextboxt.text;
    CSerialize.DLu = "\\app";

    XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CaseA));
    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/XmlPackages/" + xmlPackageFilename));
    Serializer.Serialize(Writer, CSerialize);
    Serializer.Serialize(Writer, CSerialize); 

}
```

With this button click event I get this xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CaseA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <DCText>\apptest</DCText>
    <DLU>\apptest</DLU>

</CaseA>
```

I would like to reference the other two classes to get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Addrequest>
 <Cdocument>
   <CaseA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <DCText>\apptest</DCText>
    <DLU>\apptest</DLU>

   </CaseA>
  </Cdocument>
</Addrequest>
```

Comment: If Serializer need help with unknown classes you can help it with another constructor :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're serializing an instance of `CaseA` class, which is why you're only seeing members of `CaseA` in the output. You need to create an instance of `AddRequest` and serialize that as the root, something like this:

```
CaseA cSerialize = new CaseA();
cSerialize .DCText = casetextboxt.text;
cSerialize .DLu = "\\app";

CDocument document = new CDocument();
document.CaseA = cSerialize ;

AddRequest root = new AddRequest();
root.CDocument = document;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddRequest), new Type[] { typeof(CDocument), typeof(CaseA) });
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/XmlPackages/" + xmlPackageFilename));
serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
```

As a side note, please follow C# coding standards for naming your local variables :)